# Having problems with on delete cascade clause

Tags: mysql, cascade

I got a trouble with on delete cascade. I got the next tables:

```
        CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS TABLES_PR;
    USE TABLES_PR;  
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USUARIO( Email varchar(50),Password varchar(50),Nombre varchar(50),Apellidos varchar(50),PRIMARY KEY(Email))engine=innodb;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CRIPTOMONEDAS(ID VARCHAR(10),NOMBRE VARCHAR(50) NULL,PRIMARY KEY(ID))engine=innodb;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LCRIPTO(ID VARCHAR(10),EMAIL VARCHAR(50),PRIMARY KEY(ID,EMAIL),FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES CRIPTOMONEDAS(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,FOREIGN KEY(EMAIL) REFERENCES USUARIO(EMAIL) ON DELETE CASCADE)engine=innodb;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PERFILES(EMAIL VARCHAR(50),NOMPERFIL VARCHAR(50),FOTOPERFIL VARCHAR(50), TIPOPERFIL VARCHAR(50),CANTIDAD NUMERIC(9) NULL,PRIMARY KEY(EMAIL,NOMPERFIL), FOREIGN KEY (EMAIL) REFERENCES USUARIO(EMAIL) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)engine=innodb;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PARES(ID VARCHAR(10), BASECURRENCY VARCHAR(10), QUOTECURRENCY VARCHAR(10), PRIMARY KEY(ID))engine=innodb;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LPARES(ID VARCHAR(10), NOMPERFIL VARCHAR(50),EMAIL VARCHAR(50), PRIMARY KEY(ID, NOMPERFIL,EMAIL), FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES PARES(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY(NOMPERFIL) REFERENCES PERFILES(NOMPERFIL) ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY(EMAIL) REFERENCES USUARIO(EMAIL) ON DELETE CASCADE);
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TRANSACCIONES(EMAIL VARCHAR(50),NOMPERFIL VARCHAR(50),NOMBREPAR VARCHAR(10),TIPOCOMPRA VARCHAR(15),FECHA DATETIME,CANTIDAD DOUBLE,PRECIO DOUBLE,PRIMARY KEY(EMAIL,NOMPERFIL,FECHA),FOREIGN KEY(EMAIL) REFERENCES USUARIO (EMAIL) ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY(NOMPERFIL) REFERENCES PERFILES(NOMPERFIL) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

when i delete a user from "usuario" table it should remove also the content into "perfiles" and "lpares" who match with that user. but it just happens into perfiles not in lpares and dont know why.

I just want to erase an user and remove all its content.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may be using MyISAM for the 2nd table (it might be your default engine and you didnt specify an engine in your create statement for lpares, in contrast to the other working tables). MyISAM does not support foreign keys (and, and as consequence, cascades).

Comment: I got an error #1215 adding innodb on lpares table and the same with "transacciones" thats why i didnt add on those tables:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LPARES(ID VARCHAR(10), NOMPERFIL VARCHAR(50),EMAIL VARCHAR(50), PRIMARY KEY(ID, NOMPERFIL,EMAIL), FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES PARES(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY(NOMPERFIL) REFERENCES PERFILES(NOMPERFIL) ON DELETE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY(EMAIL) REFERENCES USUARIO(EMAIL) ON DELETE CASCADE)engine=innodb;

Comment: Then maybe add that error and ask how you can make that table innodb. If you leave it MyISAM, foreign keys and cascades can not work.